# How to get Shipping Address from Create Order page?

Tags: orders, tax, admin-order-create

I know how to get the customer's default shipping address information, but how can I get a "one-time" shipping address before the order is submitted?

### Example

Customer from Georgia has default addresses in Georgia, but is shipping to Florida for this new order. If I want to know what their shipping address is for this case, how can I find out?

I need to this information for Tax Calculation purposes, so I can charge tax if the shipment is going to Florida. Is this even possible?

### edit

Based on R.S.'s suggestion, I'm trying to get an observer set up <s>but it isn't working as I expected</s>. Here is what I have currently:

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mbs_Tax>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Mbs_Tax>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <events>
            <sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
                <observers>
                    <tax>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Mbs_Tax_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>salesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore</method>
                    </tax>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Observer.php**

```
class Mbs_Tax_Model_Observer {
    public function salesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore($observer) {
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $region = $address->getData('region');
        Mage::log("Address from salesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore: region ".$region,null,"tax.log");
        if(strtoupper($region)==="FLORIDA") {

            Mage::log("Shipping to Florida: ".print_r($quote->getShippingAddress()->getData('tax_amount'), true),null,"tax.log");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an observer for `<sales_quote_collect_totals_before>`

Then in your observer

```
$quote = $observer->getQuote();
$address = $quote->getShippingAddress()
```

Comment: I set up an observer to simply write to `tax.log` (to ensure it's working first) but I either have it set up incorrectly or it's not firing where I think it is. I expect it would run after I add products to the order, before submitting the order. Is this correct?

Comment: Not setup correctly ... take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16423413/1191288

Comment: How do I save the data I'm changing (`tax_amount`)?